# Removing "System Volume Information" folder and "System Restore" completely

Tags: windows-8, system-restore, volume-shadow-copy

I disable System Restore on all drives yet it continues to force me to have a pointless System Volume Information folder set to hidden with 1 "Tracking" file inside. Can someone please explain how to delete the ENTIRE folder including the folder itself fully, completely, and permanently? I know "the purpose" of the folder. I don't want it and I don't need it. I want it deleted and to never return because I want to delete it and to have it never return.

Deleting/renaming it just makes it not disappear but become actually invisible until I refresh the root folder or go back to it, which puts it back there again, which tells me it wasn't deleted at all. I have also formatted the drive which is also a waste of time because it puts it back there, despite disabling the service. On XP I used to be able to get rid of them forever and not have to think about it because they never returned. This "upgrade", windose 8, despite the service being disabled, is not an upgrade. Upgraded things should be better. Can you tell me how to Nuke "system restore" in every way on Windose 8, please?

Thanks.

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU expect some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: Last I checked, the "Ask a question" page _did_ say "Share your research" right on the orange box [on the side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C977T.png).

Comment: "My question doesn't expect me to have done research. " you are wrong, research effort is expected here on SU or down votes will result if you do not. You should include your research efforts and what you have tried and failed, this way we do not cover the same ground twice, we help when you show research effort to resolve the issue before posting the question. This is not a Q and A forum.

Answer (score 1):

"System Volume Information" is [not specific to System Restore *at all*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031120-00/?p=41753). (The restore points are actually kept as Volume Shadow Copies starting with Windows Vista. Shadow Copies are used for other things such as the "File History" feature, which also store their *metadata* in that folder.) The folder also keeps various other kinds of NTFS metadata, and the file you mention is used is for tracking NTFS object IDs.

(So… if you claim you know "the" purpose of this folder, then you *don't* know it.)